# Commented blocks/indents interfering with code

Tags: python

The problem is best explained by just showing the code:

```
a = True
b = True
while True:
    """
    A
    """
    if a == True:
        pass
    """
    B
    """
    elif b == True:
        pass
```

The issue being that there is a syntax error at "elif b", though when removing the comments, the issue disappears. I tried removing the indents on the comments which resulted in an expected indent on the closing comment line after "A". I know I could switch to using "#" to comment sections, though """ makes things much clearer and is more convenient for large chunks. Perhaps I'm missing something obvious, I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3):

String literals aren't comments. You can sometimes sort of pretend they're comments, but they're not, and the fact that they're not is finally biting you.

An `elif` has to appear immediately after the end of the block associated with the preceding `if` or `elif`. There can be comments and whitespace in between, but no statements, and strings count. Use real comments, with `#`.

If you *really* want to keep pretending strings are comments, you can indent the B string into the body of the `if`, but it won't line up cleanly with the block it's intended to be a comment on, and you'll just keep having to mess with your formatting to patch up the differences between comments and string literals.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new string when you use `"""triple quotes"""`.  So, you essentially have an un-indented block of code before your elif, which requires a preceding if statement.  The improper tabbing on the quotes ends your `if` block.  Once your parser reaches the `elif` block, it doesn't have a matching if block, hence the error.

Triplequotes are used as docstrings in places, and can act like comments, but they're not actually comments.

[Reference (search for """)](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings)